# Unable To Sculpt On A Particular Area Of The Mesh

Tags: sculpting

I am having trouble sculpting a particular area on this monster's face. As you can see in the picture below, I was able to sculpt fur for his whole face and ears except for one particular area near his cheek (highlight in red). In this area (highlighted in red), my brush cannot affect or affect very little on the surface mesh. I have tried using Dyntopo to add more geometry but even after that my brush still had a hard time sculpting on the area. 
[image]

Besides trying to use Dyntopo to fix the problem, I have also tried "Apply Scale and Rotation" with Ctrl + A, as well as Fliping Normal with Ctrl + N.

If you know any solutions or explanation to this problem, please share.

I am using 2.79

Comment: it looks like a mask. Click on the "Hide/Mask" menu and choose "Clear mask".

Comment: sorry, it is not a mask. I edited the red part in (In Photoshop) to show the area which I am having problem sculpting.